# Getting "Validation Failed: 1: no scroll ids specified" trying to read elastic search from spark

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I am trying to read a elastic search index through a spark dataframe through spark-shell (Spark version 1.5.2).  I don't understand what a scoll-id is or what I need to do to query elastic search from spark.

spark-shell --jars /transfer/hdp/lib/elasticsearch-spark_2.10-2.3.2.jar

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import sqlContext._
import sqlContext.implicits._

// Stop current spark context to over-ride it
sc.stop()

// Create new spark config for Elastic Search
val config = new SparkConf()
config.set("es.nodes", "*elastic-search-host-name*")
config.set("es.resource", "spark_count/spark_count")
config.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

// Start new spark context
val sc = new SparkContext(config)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

// Create dataframe for reading
val sparkDF = sqlContext.esDF("spark_count/spark_count")

// Print Schema Note this works
sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- event_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_column: string (nullable = true)
 |-- spark_count: string (nullable = true)
 |-- train: string (nullable = true)

// Display 20 records
sparkDF.show()

[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 5]16/06/20 13:30:56 ERROR TaskContextImpl: Error in TaskCompletionListener
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no scroll ids specified;]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:478)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:449)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.deleteScroll(RestClient.java:512)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.close(ScrollQuery.java:70)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

In development I'm running an old version of elastic search 1.0 and while I can save data to elastic search and display index schema's the queries fail.

I tried on Elastic Search version 1.4 and it works.